# Google Spreadsheet MAX + Join of other cells

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet like this - I can't figure out how to dynamically search for this.

I want to find the MAX Score Value + output the related name
(no worries, in another column I've got the Score calculated as clean numbers without letters).

(QUERY doesn't really work because once I change a score, it doesn't update that output)

[image]

Comment: So i would like to output:

Vuk13 | 1690000
(as I said, ive got the clean numbers on another column)

Comment: You can use Index/match for this: `=INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(MAX(D2:D6),D2:D6))` (assuming the clean numbers are in column D)

Comment: For that, you can concatenate: `=INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(MAX(D2:D6),D2:D6)) & " | " & MAX(D2:D6)`

Comment: I just tried it! Thanks for helping.

Doesnt seem to work. It only gives me the last "name" of the B coloumn. In the case if B2:B6 it gives me "Lambo"

Comment: And yeah, the concatenate stuff isnt really that important. I can easily get the =MAX() value of my clean numbers coloumn. But I cant get the related name. (want to output that next to the =MAX() cell

Comment: B2:B49 with Names. AC2:AC49 with the score (clean numbers)

I want to find the player with the highest score. So I want for example B50 = Name of the player and C50 with his score

Comment: @player0 I dont know if you can see my screenshot in my question but there is one sample. Just imagine that my C coloumn has clean numbers than these string-characters (M/k)

Comment: I just found out what would be even better.
If I could DYNAMICLY sort my two coloumns... Than at the top i would have my Top 1. Player + ive got a sorted list for the 2nd / 3rd

But the output needs to be in another column because I want to be able to still change the original column dnymicly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=SORTN(SORT({x2:x, y2:y}, 2, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

where:

```
x2:x  - column with names 
y2:y  - column with values
2     - sort values
0     - in descending order
9^9   - return all rows
2     - 2nd mode of sortn eg. group by
1     - names column
1     - in ascending order
```